# Adding transition effects between horizontal slides in Fullpage JS for Elementor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have a section with horizontal slides in Elementor. I want to add a blur effect when you scroll between the slides. Is there a simple way to do this? There are different event triggers such as "onLeave", "afterLoad" etc where you can added custom code, so this may be an option, or can I simply add some CSS? Im a bit lost as to what I have to target to make this work, if anyone knows what code I can add and where that would be a huge help. sections have anchors "section1" & "section2", and Ive also added section classes "one" & "two".

Answer (score 2):

you can use [animate.css](https://animate.style/) and add its classes to your slides in show or hide